# how to install glusterfs client on alpine

Tags: docker, alpine-linux, glusterfs

I would like to mount from docker container of the alpine os to gluster-fs server.
but, I don't know how to do it.

I mean to say, I don't know how to install glusterfs client on alpine 
Has anyone succeeded it?

I know how to install glusterfs client on ubuntu.
Should i install glusterfs client on ubuntu and mount it?
Let him know if you have best practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the below two issues

https://github.com/gluster/glusterfs/issues/268

https://bugs.alpinelinux.org/issues/2834

It seems it is not possible because few functions used which are not available in case of alpine. There used to be a GlusterFS volume plugin but it seems not maintained any more

https://github.com/calavera/docker-volume-glusterfs

So best would be for you to mount the folder on host and then share it with the docker container via volumes

Comment: Thank you for your commenting. I got it could not install glusterfs client on alpine. According to your advice,I will consider it. thank you!